# How to give my remote repository url in .gitconfig file

Tags: git, github, adobe-brackets

Here I am new to Git and now install bracket IDE and Git and create a new repository in GitHub and now in bracket I need to connect to remote repository for that I install brackets Git and now I can say if I give my url in `.gitconfig` file it will automatically connect to the repository from bracket ... so can any one tell me how to give the rule in `.gitconfig` file

Below is my default content in `.gitconfig` file

```
[user]
name = xyz MV
email = abc@gmail.com
[gui]
recentrepo = F:/gitclone
```

Now please tell me what to place in this file so that bracket can automatically connect to the remote repository.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the `[remote]` directive.

```
[remote "origin"]
  url = git@github.com:user/repo.git
  fetch = ...
[remote ...]
```

The command `git remote add origin git@github.com:user/repo.git` will do this. (as nwinkler pointed out)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing is through the command line:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/.....
```

For the URL, use the one from your GitHub project page.